# If the limit exists and is smaller than 1 then $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how I can prove this Theorem. I just want to show that $\limsup<1$ it does not have to be necessarily $\leq \lim$ in the proof Maybe this would make it easier?

My efforts:

Let $\lim <q < 1$ then $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|\leq$ for $n\geq N$.

Let $n>N$ then $|a_n| \leq |a_N|q^{n-N}$

I want to use this for my estimate but I don't know how, in particular why can $\limsup$ not be $=1$ under those conditions?

$$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq\sqrt[n]{q^{n-N}|a_N|}=q^{\frac{n-N}{n}}\sqrt[n]{|a_N|}=\frac{1}{q^{\frac{N}{n}}}\sqrt[n]{|a_N|}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{|a_N|}}{\sqrt[n]{q^N}}$$

Nominator converges to $1$ and denominator converges to $1$.

Can somebody help me with a hint?

Edit:

$q^{\frac{n-N}{n}}=q\cdot q^{-\frac{N}{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $q < 1$ at all.  Assume that $a_n > 0$ for all $n$ and that $q > \limsup \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

As you observe there exists an index $N$ with the property that $$n \ge N \implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < q$$ which leads to 
$$ n > N \implies a_n < a_N q^{n-N}.$$
As long as $n > N$ it follows that
$$\sqrt[n]{a_n} < q \sqrt[n]{\dfrac{a_N}{q^N}}. $$
It is well known that for any $a > 0$ that $\sqrt[n]{a} \to 1$, so in particular $\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{a_N}{q^N}} = 1$ because $N$ is fixed. Now calculate the limsup above:
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} q\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{a_N}{q^N}} = q  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\dfrac{a_N}{q^N}} = q$$ 
This is independent of $N$ so finally take the infimum over all $q > \limsup \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ to find $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} \le \limsup \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.$$